# Solr boost query with bq parmeter

Tags: django, solr, lucene, full-text-search, django-haystack

Is there any difference between the following queries?

Query 1:

```
bq=field1:x^2+field2:y^4
```

Query 2:

```
bq=field1:x^2&bq=field2:y^4
```

If any, how can I replicate Query 2 using 'bq' parameter only once?

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these are `bq` parameters. BQ stands for Boost Queries, and is not meant to supply only field names, but rather queries by themselves (`field1:value^2` for example).

If you want to weight fields, use `qf` with their inherent weights instead.

That being said, `bq` parameters are additive as far as I can see, so you should have the same results. Look at debugQuery for how the generated query is parsed to see what the difference is if you're seeing any.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited the question.

But when I fire these 2 statements into solr, I get different results. That's why I wanted to know, how to imitate the second statement.

Comment: Please check the output from debugQuery to see the difference: according to the community wiki it might be `If you want your query to be parsed as separate clauses with separate boosts, use multiple bq parameters.`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to imitate the second statement by passing bq as a list in haystack. And to.my surprise solr treated the list of params as multiple bq parameters.(Also I made some changes to the solr backend of haystack to accept raw parameters.)